# Why is isalpha() not working for lowercase letters?

Tags: c

In the code below, the first statement is printed if the character is a capital letter but for a lower case letter the second statement is printed.  What is the reason for this?  I am using dev c++ to compile my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    printf("enter a character\n");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    int i;
    i=isalpha(c);
    if(i==1)
        printf("entered character is an alphabet\n");
    else
        printf("entered character is not an alphabet\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you read the manual of `isalpha()`, it says: `The values returned are non-zero if the character c falls into the tested class, and a zero value if not.` That should help you understand the problem.

Comment: `i=isalpha(c);` --> `i=!!isalpha(c);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY or just `if(isalpha(c))`

Answer (score 6):

`isalpha` can return any nonzero value for an alphabetic character, not just `1`. So change `if(i==1)` to `if(i)`.

Answer (score 5):

The standard does not require `isalpha` to return zero or one. It requires it to return zero or non-zero. Any non-zero value indicates `true`: ([documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha))

> #### Return value
>
> Non-zero value (true) if the character is an alphabetic character, 0 (false) otherwise.

For example, the implementation installed on ideone returns 1024 ([demo](http://ideone.com/VYBcJF)).

Changing the `if(i==1)` code to `if(i!=0)` or even `if(i)` will fix this problem.